# Email Form CSS and HTML won't work well

Tags: html, css

I have a site here: http://desertcinema.com/gold/

And I have a form there that doesn't work good especially when you click inside the input tag.

[image]

I want to make it exactly like the normal state even when you hover or click your mouse on it. But it seems my CSS and HTML doesnt work that way.

Here's the CSS:

```
.email-icon i {
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 71px;
}

.contact-form .form-group {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 4px !important;
}
.contact-form {
    color: #8C8C8C;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 60px auto;
}

.contact-form input {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 22% 0 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #dadada;
}
.contact-form .error:focus,
.contact-form .error {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
        background-color: #ffffff;
}
.contact-form label.error {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-transform: none;
    top: -28px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.contact-form .email-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 12px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.contact-form .btn-submit {
     font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #3498db;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

You can use chrome's INSPECT TOOL if you want to check and diagnose this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In style.css this is the piece that is overriding the padding on hover:

```
textarea, 
input[type="text"], 
input[type="text"]:hover, 
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="text"]:active,
input[type="email"], 
input[type="email"]:hover, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:active{
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Updating the attribute values for padding there to the following seemed to work:

```
textarea, 
input[type="text"], 
input[type="text"]:hover, 
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="text"]:active,
input[type="email"], 
input[type="email"]:hover, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:active{
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 22% 0 70px;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

If you want your original setting to stick, I suppose you could always change:

```
.contact-form input {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 22% 0 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #dadada;
}
```

To this:

```
.contact-form input {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 22% 0 70px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #dadada;
}
```

Comment: It actually fix it however How can I stick with the same design when hover mode? such as the white background and so.

Comment: Well you're just having conflicts between 2 sets of properties.  Maybe another solution to use instead if you just want to apply the one style for this email box is to remove this line completely: (hit enter prematurely sorry) input[type="email"]:hover,

Comment: Maybe even take all of these out if they are causing conflicts (noticed a brief 'flash' as the white box disappeared when I clicked in the email box, if I left some of the others behind for example):  `input[type="email"], 
input[type="email"]:hover, 
input[type="email"]:focus, 
input[type="email"]:active`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this.

> 1. open your file: /gold/css/style.css
> 2. Goto line number 108 in file
> 3. remove padding: 9px;

you will have like this,

```
textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:active, input[type="email"], input[type="email"]:hover, input[type="email"]:focus, input[type="email"]:active {
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    /* padding: 9px; */
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.contact-form:focus,.contact-hover:focus{
background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 22% 0 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #dadada;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Did you use your inspect element tool on chrome or firefox?